# Find the Mono version on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

When trying to connect to Mac on Visual Studio on Windows, I'm told that the version on the Mac is different and am asked by VS if I want it to install Mono on the Mac.

But the version on the Mac is newer.

From experience, I've seen that trying to do that created more trouble rather than help.

So I'd like to search for how to update the Mono version on Windows/VS, but I can't seem to find anywhere an option to do that. So I want to find out what version is "installed" on VS.

Comment: Which Mono do you need? Maybe you could right-click your solution, manage the NuGet- packages and search for "Mono". Or look into the "installed" tab in your NuGet- Package Manager.

Comment: @Sunburst275 It's not there :)

Comment: Oh okay then maybe look into your installed extensions? Theres also a Xamarin entry. Maybe that helps you

Comment: It seems to that the Mono version is tied to the Visual Studio version on WIndows,you could not change it.But on mac ,you could change it by upgrading or downgrading the xamarin.ios version to keep the same as the version on Windows.

Comment: What's the exact error message? Typical ones are already there in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#warning-messages

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to be working predominantly on a windows machine, then let it install whatever version the visual studio wants. Sometimes windows visual studio will use a different version than mac visual studio. The environment you're working in should dictate what version you use.